# 2 SQL Queries into one array and then sort array and dispaly

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have two SQL queries that I want to store in one array that can be sorted.

SQL 1

```
$sql = "SELECT ItemRelation.ItemRelTo, ItemRelation.Item, Items.CatID, Items.ItemID,   
Items.Title, Items.Image, Items.Desc, Items.TimeStamp
FROM Items
INNER JOIN ItemRelation 
ON ItemRelation.ItemRelTo=Items.ItemID
WHERE ItemRelation.Item = " . $filterbyitem;
```

SQL 2

```
$sql2 = "SELECT ItemRelation.ItemRelTo, ItemRelation.Item, Items.CatID, Items.ItemID,     
Items.Title, Items.Image, Items.Desc, Items.TimeStamp
FROM Items
INNER JOIN ItemRelation
ON ItemRelation.Item=Items.ItemID
WHERE ItemRelation.ItemRelTo = " . $filterbyitem;
```

Now I list them with two arrays, but want to get them into one so I can sort by Items.TimeStamp and then dispaly them in a list. Or is it possible to make one SQL query of them both?

I can add that the join condition is different in the queried.

Comment: I think it should be possible the combine the queries themselves. Have you looked into UNION?

Comment: can't you merge the 2 queries to one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make one query out of the two by using UNION:

```
$sql = "SELECT ItemRelation.ItemRelTo, ItemRelation.Item, Items.CatID, Items.ItemID,   
Items.Title, Items.Image, Items.Desc, Items.TimeStamp
FROM Items
INNER JOIN ItemRelation 
ON ItemRelation.ItemRelTo=Items.ItemID
WHERE ItemRelation.Item = " . $filterbyitem . "
UNION
SELECT ItemRelation.ItemRelTo, ItemRelation.Item, Items.CatID, Items.ItemID,     
Items.Title, Items.Image, Items.Desc, Items.TimeStamp
FROM Items
INNER JOIN ItemRelation
ON ItemRelation.Item=Items.ItemID
WHERE ItemRelation.ItemRelTo = " . $filterbyitem;
```

Then you can order them within the query and the returned result will already be in the order you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use the SQL `OR` statement combined with the `ORDER BY` to sort them.

```
"WHERE ItemRelation.Item = ".$filterbyitem." OR 
  ItemRelation.ItemRelTo = ".$filterbyitem." ORDER BY Items.TimeStamp";
```

No need for managing arrays in php.

Comment: This is best answer. No need for a union here when the only thing different in the queries is a different WHERE condition.  Simply combine those to WHERE conditions with an `OR` and you will have what you need.

Comment: here you can also sort with `ORDER BY Items.TimeStamp`

Comment: The Join is also different

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this function :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
<?php
    $result = array_merge($sql1, $sql2);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR statement, and make sure you use it in the ON command as well as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT ItemRelation.ItemRelTo, ItemRelation.Item, Items.CatID, Items.ItemID,   
Items.Title, Items.Image, Items.Desc, Items.TimeStamp
FROM Items
INNER JOIN ItemRelation 
ON ((ItemRelation.ItemRelTo=Items.ItemID) OR (ItemRelation.Item=Items.ItemID))
WHERE ItemRelation.Item = " . $filterbyitem."
OR ItemRelation.ItemRelTo = " . $filterbyitem;
```

I don't think some people have noticed that your ON clauses aren't the same.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  You can add the "Distinct" property for that.  I've edited the query above to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

Since both queries are identical except for the condition, you could just rewrite as:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE $filterbyitem IN (ItemRelation.Item, ItemRelation.ItemRelTo)
ORDDER BY TimeStamp
```

Comment: The join condition is also diffrent